# Only divide by the number of times a specific string appears, not the total length (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement

I'm trying to get the average "level" for freshman and sophomores. I'm added the answers together at this point, but I'm not sure how to get the total number of answers only for the items matching "Freshman" or "Sophomore." I used len = gdata.length to count the total number of items in the array, but I need to recount for only the matching answers.

```
var len = gdata.length;
    var sum = 0;
    var sumF = 0;
    var sumSo = 0;
    var average = 0;
    var avgF = 0;
    var avgSo = 0;

$.each(gdata, function (i, gdata){

            var date = gdata.Timestamp;
    var level = gdata.level;
    var year = gdata.year;
            sum+=parseInt(level) || 0;
            average = sum/len;


    switch(year) {
      case 'Freshman':
        sumF+=parseInt(level) || 0;
        console.log(sumF);
        avgF = sumF/len;
        break;

      case 'Sophomore':
        sumSo+=parseInt(level) || 0;
        console.log(sumSo);
        avgSo = sumSo/len;
        break;

      default:
        console.log("");
    }

});
    console.log(sum);
    console.log(average);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter the array first using jQuery.grep.  [enter link description here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/#arraycallbackinvert)

```
var fsData = $.grep(gdata, function (n, i) {
    return n.year == "Freshman" || n.year == "Sophomore";
});
```

Then fsData.length will be the total number of freshman and sophomores.  Then your each statement could be adjusted to:

```
$.each(fsData, function (i, data) {
    // blah blah
});
```

EDIT:

If you want to separate out the freshman and sophomores, you could do something like this:

```
var freshman = [];
var sophomores = [];
var freshman_and_sophomores = [];

$.each(gdata, function (i, v) {
    if (v.year == "Freshman" || v.year == "Sophomore") {
        freshman_and_sophomores.push(v);
        if (v.year == "Freshman") freshman.push(v);
        if (v.year == "Sophomore") sophomores.push(v);
    }
});
```

Now you can grab freshman.length and sophomores.length.  Then use freshman_and_sophomores in your next $.each.

Comment: Ok, so I sort of understand what this is doing. How do I access the number of Freshman and Sophomores separately, though? Say fsData.length is equal to 11, accounting for six freshman and five sophomores. How do I grab/save the six and the five?